# Перестановка из массива в массив

Tags: java, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть массив с уже существующим набором эллементов, для примера :

> [A][B][C][D][E][F]

то есть n-элементов.

Нужно разместить их в меньший массив размером k-элементов без повторов, получить все возможные варианты в данном случае по формуле без учета порядка и без возвращения должно получиться 40 вариантов. Как реализовать такой алгоритм, желательно на java.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/generating_combinations читали?

Comment: нет, но мне бы как нибудь через рекурсию